# Resteasy javax - How to map content-type */* to application/json on server-side?

Tags: java, json, wildfly, resteasy, content-type

Problem: I cannot get a content-type of `*/*` in the client message to map to `application/json` on the server side by changing the server code and not the client code. (Too many deployed clients to do the latter)

On WildFly 10 everything works as is (with the `*/*`), but on WildFly 14/18 it fails with

```
RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class xxxx of content type: */* at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-
jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound
```

All the above is on Java 8. The code below shows the client-side change that would get WF14+ to work without server-side edits:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "*/*");  // works for WF10, not WF14+
// conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"); // works for all
```

The applicable server side code is as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("fileDownload")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
// Consume options tried that still failed:
// @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.WILDCARD, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "*/*", "*/*\r\n", "*/*; charset=UTF-8" } )
public Response fileDownload(@HeaderParam("Range") String range, FileDownloadRequest fileDwnReq) throws IOException { ... }
```

My net searches all point to client-side changes (which will work) but we have to change the server-side or stay on WF10. I have also tried setting charset behaviour or mapping the media type in the *web.xml* but it made no difference. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyRestServices</display-name>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!--   
    To specify the previous behavior, in which UTF-8 was used for text media types, but 
    the explicit charset was not appended, the context parameter "resteasy.add.charset" may be 
    set to "false". It defaults to "true". 
    See https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.2.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html
    This did not work.
     -->
<!--     <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>resteasy.add.charset</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>false</param-value> -->
<!--     </context-param> -->
        
     <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.media.type.mappings</param-name>
        <param-value>*/* : application/json</param-value>
<!-- <param-value>html : text/html, json : application/json, xml : application/xml</param-value> -->
    </context-param>
```

I am stumped. Any suggestions/pointers will be appreciated.

Edit: Below is a dump of the failing http request:

```
 URI=/xxx/fileDownload
 characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=94
       contentType=[*/*]
            header=Accept=text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Type=*/*
            header=Content-Length=94
            header=User-Agent=Java/1.8.0_152
            header=Host=127.0.0.1:8014
            locale=[]
            method=POST
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:59867
        remoteHost=127.0.0.1
            scheme=http
              host=127.0.0.1:8014
        serverPort=8014
          isSecure=false
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=0
       contentType=null
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Length=0
            header=Date=Thu, 20 Aug 2020 13:36:44 GMT
            status=415
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way by adding a ContainerRequestFilter that changes the header before matching. Below did the trick:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;

@Provider
@PreMatching
// Mapp */* to JSON for /filedownload
public final class ContentFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
      UriInfo uri = ctx.getUriInfo();
      if ((uri != null) && uri.getPath().toLowerCase().contains("filedownload")) {
          String ctp = ctx.getHeaderString("Content-Type");
          if ("*/*".equals(ctp))
             ctx.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      }
   }
}
```

I also had to add the following to my web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>xxx.yyy.ContentFilter</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using wildcards in "Content-Type" on the client-side makes no sense.

The *client* may accept server responses in multiple format (using the "Accept" header)

The *server* may accept (consume) multiple media, but the client has to know what kind of data he is effectively posting. If you do not tell the server what you are sending in the http body, the server cannot (always) guess it.

Comment: I agree that it does not make sense; however that is what is already in the field and I have to find a way to get it to still work on WF18 until we can fix the clients.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.5.6.Final/userguide/html/Content_Marshalling_Providers.html#Default_Providers_and_default_JAX-RS_Content_Marshalling) you should be able get the request body as a String parameter and subsequently marshal it manually to your desired object form.